# Responsive Table Mobile Buttons Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, responsive

I setup a responsive table at the bottom of [this page](https://sewingprofessionals.com/why-join-ASDP). I need help figuring out why the buttons in mobile view don't work.

The code I'm using is from [this page](https://codepen.io/adrianjacob/pen/KdVLXY)

```
    <!-- DIRTY Responsive pricing table HTML -->

<article>

<ul>
  <li class="bg-purple">
    <button>Self-Employed</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Simple Start</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue active">
    <button>Essentials</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Plus</button>
  </li>
</ul>  

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hide"></th>
      <th class="bg-purple">Self-Employed</th>
      <th class="bg-blue">Simple Start</th>
      <th class="bg-blue default">Essentials</th>
      <th class="bg-blue">Plus</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Monthly price</td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">6</span></td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">7</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">15</span></td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">25</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="sep">Get started easily</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Includes free updates and new features as they become available</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No software to install — sign up online in moments</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Import customer & supplier details from Excel, Outlook and .csv</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accept card payments in QuickBooks Online</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="sep">Stay protected and get support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Free telephone and online support</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Strong encryption protects your business data</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Automatic data backups</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</article>
```

The headings at the top of the table are suppose to be clickable but they don't work.

As a sidenote, I added a class of .matrix so that the ul and li css didn't interfere with the site's main navigation's ul.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would it be possible to add the CSS you are using to target this HMTL, and place the code in a runnable snippet?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 groups of header: ul -> li and thead -> th.
!important css override the jquery css style.

```js
// DIRTY Responsive pricing table JS
function showColumn(element) {
    $("#pricing tr").find('td:not(:first)').hide();
    $("#pricing tr").find('th:not(:first)').hide();
    $("#pricing .active").removeClass('active');
    
    var pos = element.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "th" ? element.index() + 1 : element.index() + 2;
    $('#pricing td:nth-child('+pos+')').show();
    $('#pricing th:nth-child('+pos+')').addClass('active').show();  
    $("#pricing .sep").prop("colspan", $("#pricing tr:first").find("th:visible").length);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pricing ul").show();
    $("#pricing ul").on("click", "li", function() {
      showColumn($(this));  
    }); 
    $("#pricing table").on("click", "#pricing thead th:not(:first)", function() {
      showColumn($(this));  
    });
  $("#pricing table").one("click", "#pricing thead th:first", function() {
      $("#pricing td,th").css('display','table-cell');
      $("#pricing .sep").prop("colspan", $("#pricing tr:first").find("th:visible").length);       
    });
  $("#pricing table").find("thead th:first").trigger("click");
  $("#pricing table").find("thead th:nth-child(2)").trigger("click");
}); 

// Initialize the media query
  var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)');
  
  // Add a listen event
  mediaQuery.addListener(doSomething);
  
  // Function to do something with the media query
  function doSomething(mediaQuery) {    
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
      $('#pricing .sep').attr('colspan',5);
    } else {
      $('#pricing .sep').attr('colspan',2);
    }
  }
  
  // On load
  doSomething(mediaQuery);
```

```css
/* DIRTY Responsive pricing table CSS */

/* 
- make mobile switch sticky
*/
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
   outline: 0;
}
body { 
  font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:14px;
}
article {
  width:100%;
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:1000px;
  position:relative;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
  top:0px;
  z-index:10;
  padding-bottom:14px;
}
li {
  list-style:none;
  flex:1;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right:1px solid #DDD;
}
button {
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-right:0;
  border-top:0;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#FFF;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  height:60px;
  color:#999
}
li.active button {
  background:#F5F5F5;
  color:#000;
}
table { border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; width:100%; }
th { background:#F5F5F5; display:none; }
td, th {
  height:53px
}
td,th { border:1px solid #DDD; padding:10px; empty-cells:show; }
td,th {
  text-align:left;
}
td+td, th+th {
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}
td.default {
  display:table-cell;
}
.bg-purple {
  border-top:3px solid #A32362;
}
.bg-blue {
  border-top:3px solid #0097CF;
}
.sep {
  background:#F5F5F5;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.txt-l { font-size:28px; font-weight:bold; }
.txt-top { position:relative; top:-9px; left:-2px; }
.tick { font-size:18px; color:#2CA01C; }
.hide {
  border:0;
  background:none;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  ul {
    display:none;
  }
  td,th {
    display:table-cell;
  }
  td,th {
    width: 330px;
  
  }
  td+td, th+th {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- DIRTY Responsive pricing table HTML -->
<div id="topBar">
<div style="float:left; width: 80%">Guest</div>
<div style="float:right; text-align:right; width: 20%">Search</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<article>
<div id="pricing">
<ul>
  <li class="bg-purple">
    <button>Self-Employed</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Simple Start</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue active">
    <button>Essentials</button>
  </li>
  <li class="bg-blue">
    <button>Plus</button>
  </li>
</ul>  

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hide"></th>
      <th class="bg-purple">Self-Employed</th>
      <th class="bg-blue">Simple Start</th>
      <th class="bg-blue default">Essentials</th>
      <th class="bg-blue">Plus</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Monthly price</td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">6</span></td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">7</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">15</span></td>
      <td><span class="txt-top">&pound;</span><span class="txt-l">25</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="sep">Get started easily</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Includes free updates and new features as they become available</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No software to install — sign up online in moments</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Import customer & supplier details from Excel, Outlook and .csv</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Accept card payments in QuickBooks Online</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="sep">Stay protected and get support</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Free telephone and online support</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Strong encryption protects your business data</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Automatic data backups</td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td class="default"><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
      <td><span class="tick">&#10004;</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: The new javascript has improved the table's display on mobile a lot! Thank you!

But upon loading, it shows the entire table. It's only until you click on a button that it shows the single section. But if you click in the hidden space above the cell that reads "Annual Membership Dues" it shows the entire table again. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Changed $("article table").on("click") to $("article table").one("click"). Then you clicked which column for user $("article table").find("thead th:nth-child(2)").trigger("click");

Comment: Working great! Is there a way to isolate the code so that it doesn't affect the table at the top of the page that contains the Login, Search bar and social icons? It has disappeared after that last change.

Comment: It should be identified by unique id contained by different divs.

Comment: They both have unique ids. So I was able to make the login button, search bar and social icons at the top display by adding 
#id_223lJck {
    display: contents !important;
}

So it looks like everything is working now. I appreciate your help!